# Deploy Spray app on AWS beanstalk

Tags: scala, sbt, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spray

I would like to deploy a simple Scala Spray app on AWS Beanstalk. I'm using a Spray example web application [spray-servlet-webapp](https://github.com/markkolich/spray-servlet-webapp). It works fine when I run it locally with `sbt start`. Also, I can build a `jar` file with `sbt compile`. But to upload it to AWS elastic beanstalk (Tomcat environment) I need to build a `war` file. I've tried to use [sbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin) but `sbt container:start` doesn't work. Probably, it is because spray is using it's own `spray-can` container. So, how to build a proper `war` file to upload it to Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [spray-servlet doc](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-servlet/#packaging-a-war-file), you should use [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin) and command `sbt package`